# Is there anyway to hide partial/element of a html source when viewing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encryption

## I know this is not possible in direct. Just checking if there is any work-around, or :source specific api's.

Anyone know a method or a trick to hide part of the html source code when view from view-source code option in the browser?

e.g. view-source:https://www.someurl.com/

I need to hide part of a source code, for an **example** a javascript tag or a div element.

---

Any possibility of achieving it by javascript?

> *Idea is not to secure the script, but to ignore when code copying.*

I know what's come to client will download to local, but as I mentioned this is **not to SECURE** a script. **But just to ignoring it in code copying**.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to hide your source code. Don't even bother encrypting it - it's a waste of time. If you want to keep something secret then don't send it to the client; process it on the server.

Comment: youre source belong to us

Comment: Have you heard about minification/uglification of js ?

Comment: @ClydeLobo: I know minification. My Approach is different. Thanks though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks for the comment. My approach is different here. Please see the updated question. I'm just researching about this.

Comment: Sorry, it's still a 'not possible'. Anything that is sent to the client can be seen by the user. Obfuscated/minified code can still be easily read.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Anyway thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't hide, you can obfuscate

You can always access what is going over the web. In javascript, if you want people to not be able to figure out what is going on, you can use an obfuscator to make it a bit more difficult. But you can not hide it entirely.

I haven't used an obfuscator for javascript myself at this point, but a quick google search turned up [this one](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx). I'm sure you can find both free and commercial alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for tip @Dylan. That is something interesting. But my goal is not to make it difficult to read but not show the script at once. Actually it's just a research question I got today.

Answer (score 1):

Anything and everything which is **downloaded by the user's browser is his/her to keep**. You cannot **"hide"** any client-side code from the user. What you can do is you can [**obfuscate**](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/) or [**minify**](https://javascript-minifier.com/) or use the [**javascript packer**](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) to make it harder for the user to figure out the logic of your code

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just got to know about obfuscate. As mentioned my research idea is different there. And it's not directly pointing to a script. As mentioned in my question, its just an example.

Comment: Well if you want to ignore it in code copying. The simplest way is to store all your javascript code in a different file and link in to your HTML file

Comment: @JayGhosh then they could just navigate to the script and look at it that way though.

Comment: Hi @JayGhosh as mentioned its not only for javascript. I know injecting html will work. But just checking for trick. :)

Comment: @JeradRutnam Ok I get it. Well the "view-source" command of the browser shows everything which the browser downloaded from the server. So there is no way to hide that.

Comment: @DylanMeeus Yes I know. But as he said, he doesn't wanna secure it. He just wants it to be hidden when someone views the source code

Comment: @JayGhosh that is true. Your answer is correct in that regard, but it wouldn't be very 'hidden' though. If someone can figure out how to see the source code, they can figure out how to copy paste the javascript from an external file. But yes, a plain copy-paste would be prevented I assume :)

Comment: Well I don't really know why he needs it. Maybe to prevent a bot from copying it into a database? ;)